# how can i find intersection points of these axlines?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, scikit-image

I want to extract the intersection point of these axlines, how can that be achieved ?

I want to extract the points and use them for homography matrix.

```
#######################
# Load and Show image #
#######################

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
import cv2 as cv
from skimage import io
link = "https://i.imgur.com/WKiQZgj.jpeg"
a = io.imread(link)
a = cv.cvtColor(a, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
figure(figsize=(15,10), dpi = 75)
plt.imshow(a,cmap = "gray")

##############
# Plot Lines #
##############

#red
plt.axline([361, 39], [1051, 15], color = "red")

#blue
plt.axline([1048, 75], [1158, 115], color = "blue")

#green 
plt.axline([361, 229], [1051, 160], color = "green")

#yellow 
plt.axline([123, 75], [151, 115], color = "yellow")
```

[output_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gBEG.png)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Juancheeto i found the solution, leaving the code as reference

```
#######################
# Load and Show Image #
#######################

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
import cv2 as cv
from scipy.stats import linregress
from skimage import io

link = "https://i.imgur.com/WKiQZgj.jpeg"
a = io.imread(link)
a = cv.cvtColor(a, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
figure(figsize=(15,10), dpi = 75)
plt.imshow(a,cmap = "gray")


# Plotting line
#green 
plt.axline([361, 229], [1051, 160], color = "green",zorder = 1)

#yellow 
plt.axline([123, 75], [151, 115], color = "yellow", zorder = 2)

########################################################
# Finding intersection point For Green And Yellow Line #
########################################################

############################## 
# Find slopes and intercepts #
##############################


# Line 1 [Yellow]
x_yellow = [123, 75] 
y_yellow = [151, 115]

slope_yellow , intercept_yellow, r_value, p_value, std_err = linregress(x_yellow, y_yellow)

# Line 2 [Green]
x_green = [361, 229]
y_green = [1051, 160]

slope_green , intercept_green, r_value, p_value, std_err = linregress(x_green, y_green)


###########################
# Find X intersect point  #
###########################

x = (intercept_green - intercept_yellow) / (slope_yellow - slope_green)


###########################
# Find Y intersect point  #                        
###########################

y = ( slope_yellow * x ) + intercept_yellow

########################################
# Plotting intersection point #
########################################


# Intersection point
plt.scatter(x,y, marker = "x", color = "black", s = 75, zorder = 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's too much to write for me to give you a working code, but I'll point out a resource and provide further suggestions, in case you are open to taking them.

1. [How to detect where two line segments intersect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/565282/9870343). To get you started on the math, here's what the `p` and `s` variables would be for the "yellow" line.

```py
p = np.array([[123, 151]])
s = p - np.array([[75,115]])
```

2. There's no need for using OpenCV and Scikit-Image. You can remove the OpenCV lines and replace them with this.

```
from skimage import color
a = color.rgb2gray(a)
```

3. Scikit-Image can also help with the homography. See the [`ProjectiveTransform`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.transform.html#projectivetransform) class. You'll want to use the `estimate` instance method therein.